# Is there a different animation between the first aid and the Adrenaline Syringe?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Is there a difference in these two animations or are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I observed today while playing a 3rd person match that when you use the adrenaline syringe, you stab it into your chest.  With first aid kits, you stab the syringe into your arm.  So yes, the animations are different.

Note that it takes 6 seconds to use both of these items now (since the revamped guns update).